# What's the kitten's and puppy's sound called?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Dogs bark but what do kittens and puppies do?

Comment: Kittens mewl, puppies whimper. But what does the fox say?

Comment: Meow: The sound made by a cat/kitten. Also see purr, etc. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_communication

Comment: Newborn puppies whimper, some older puppies yip.

Comment: @pyobum Fox's actually make a yelp/yip sound similar to dogs.

Comment: @zeel Thank you, but that wasn't a serious question. It was a pop culture reference.

Comment: @pyobum I was aware, and did not care.

Comment: @zeel No worries, then. Now the OP knows the sound of puppies, kittens, **and** foxes.

Answer (score 1):

Kittens and puppies may make the same sounds as adults to some extent - just as adults may make less mature sounds.

Cats: Meow, purr, cry, mewl, hiss.

Dogs: Bark, yap, yip, whimper, whine, groan, growl.

"Bark", "yap", and "yip" are really the same vocalization - smaller breeds and puppies just can't manage as low of a "bark" as larger dogs.